# Gitignore not ignoring certain project.properties

Tags: android, git

I am using the github app for windows and mac and I am having a problem with my .gitignore file.

I am trying to ignore the project.properties file that gets generated when switch between my two machines but I simply cannot seem to get it to work.

Below is a copy of my .gitignore, and it seems to be working well for everything except for the project.properties, as well as the gen/* that I have in there yet that is less annoying.

I have been researching this for a while and haven't found an answer, I would appreciate any help!

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
`enter code here`proguard/

#Log Files
*.log

project.properties
*.properties
project.properties
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suspect you added the project.properties line to .gitignore after that file had been committed.

What you need to do is the following:

`git rm --cached project.properties`

and for gen/*

`git rm --cached gen/`

Then commit.

the --cached option will unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone. [git-rm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

Comment: Ahh you are correct, thanks a bunch this actually made me understand github a lot more than I previously did.

Comment: Excellent. You should note, however, my answer is not limited to GitHub - which is just a hosting service for software projects using Git version control software. If your question has been resolved, please consider accepting the answer too.